# FilterExpression on SQLDataSource in c#

Tags: c#, .net

What does the FilterExpression do on a SQLDataSource in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It controls the filtering expression that is applied when a `Select` method call is issued. Read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterexpression.aspx).

So if you have something like:

```vb
FilterExpression="Title='{0}'
```

Then you can filter on Title when you call `Select`, and supply the title value.